# IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts

I am using Terraform to deploy a GCP organization policy at the project level (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/org_policy_policy)
the service account has 2 roles: Organization Policy Administrator and serviceAccountTokenCreator.
Terraform init and apply to show the number of items to be deployed. terraform apply reports

```
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
"status": "permission_Denied",
"details":{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "iam_permission_denied",
"domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
```

The roles given to the service account are Organization Policy Administrator and serviceAccountTokenCreator.
I have tested with several roles and nothing. I am not able to figure out what I am missing.
Could you please assist me?